# Change bar color of chart if the amount doesn't meet the condition

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart

How can I change the color of the `bar` in the `chart` if the total amount is lower than 5,000?

Here is my code..

```
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d-%y') date, SUM(totalamount) totalamt FROM tblsales WHERE month(date) = month(now()) GROUP BY date");
        cmd.Connection = dbConn;

        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            this.chart1.Series["Month"].Points.AddXY(rdr["date"].ToString(), rdr.GetDouble("totalamt"));
        }

        rdr.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: You don't say which charting library you're using; the answer would depend on the functionality of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color of a Bar by the `Color` property of the `DataPoint`:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[i].Color = Color.Red;
```

However there are no expressions for the `Color` property, so you have to set it whenever the data are set or changed..

You can either do it while adding the `DataPoints`:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    int index = this.chart1.Series["Month"].Points.AddXY(rdr["date"].ToString(),
                                                         rdr.GetDouble("totalamt"));
    if (rdr.GetDouble("totalamt") < 5000) 
        this.chart1.Series["Month"].Points[index].Color = Color.Red;
}
```

Or you can write a function to update the colors later:

```
void SetColors(Series s, Color color, double limit)
{
    foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points)
        if (dp.YValues[0] < limit) dp.Color = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using ASP.NET Charts. For the same you can do something like

```
chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Green;
```

Choose whatever Color suits you as per the Values in If Else Conditions.